# XSLT: Repeat output of value by n times while "n" is given value of another attribute

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm rather new to XSLT and currently looking for a solution for my problem:

I would like to output a node `<artnr><xsl:value-of select="sku" /></artnr>`
n-times, where "n" is the value of another attribute `<xsl:value-of select="qty" />`.
For example:
"sku" has the value 12345, "qty" has the value 3.
The output should look like this:

```
<products>
<artnr>12345</artnr>
<artnr>12345</artnr>
<artnr>12345</artnr>
</products>
```

So far I have prepared the following template, but it is not very efficient:

```
<products>
  <xsl:for-each select="items/item">
    <xsl:if test="qty = 1">
            <artnr><xsl:value-of select="sku" /></artnr>
    </xsl:if>
    <xsl:if test="qty = 2">
            <artnr><xsl:value-of select="sku" /></artnr>
            <artnr><xsl:value-of select="sku" /></artnr>
    </xsl:if>
    <!-- etc. -->
  </xsl:for-each>
</products>
```

To cover all realistic cases, this approach definitely isn't acceptable. This issue has been discussed here in similar cases a couple of times already, but I cannot make it work on my own example.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What version of XSLT? Answers will vary greatly depending on version.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention I'm forced to use XSLT 1.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example of a recursive template if you're limited to 1.0.

Thanks for the sample XML input @Valdi_Bo :-)

Note: This assumes that `qty` will be greater than zero. If a qty can be zero, you'll need to add a test before outputting `artnr`.

**XML Input**

```
<items>
    <item>
        <qty>3</qty>
        <sku>12345</sku>
    </item>
    <item>
        <qty>2</qty>
        <sku>23456</sku>
    </item>
    <item>
        <qty>1</qty>
        <sku>34567</sku>
    </item>
</items>
```

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="items">
    <products>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </products>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="item">
    <xsl:call-template name="output_sku"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template name="output_sku">
    <xsl:param name="qty" select="qty"/>
    <xsl:variable name="remaining_qty" select="$qty - 1"/>
    <artnr>
      <xsl:value-of select="sku"/>
    </artnr>
    <xsl:if test="$remaining_qty >= 1">
      <xsl:call-template name="output_sku">
        <xsl:with-param name="qty" select="$remaining_qty"/>
      </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output**

```
<products>
   <artnr>12345</artnr>
   <artnr>12345</artnr>
   <artnr>12345</artnr>
   <artnr>23456</artnr>
   <artnr>23456</artnr>
   <artnr>34567</artnr>
</products>
```

Fiddle: http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/bnnZVQ/1

Comment: "*If a qty can be zero, you'll need to add a test before outputting artnr.*" Or move the existing test to where it rightly belongs: http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/bnnZVQ/2

Comment: Daniel, you made my day! That's exactly I was looking for, thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

In **XSLT 2.0**, among variants of `xsl:for-each` loop there is
`select="1 to <final_value>"`.

In your case this *final_value* is given by `qty` element.

But one additional action is needed. Because inside `xsl:for-each` the context
item is changed to the current element of the loop (in this case a number),
you have to:

- save the "outer" context (the current `item` element) in a variable
  (I called it `itm`),
- use this variable as the start point of *XPath* expression referring to `sku`
  child element.

So the whole script can look like below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
  <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <products>
      <xsl:for-each select="items/item">
        <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:variable name="itm" select="."/>
          <xsl:for-each select="1 to qty">
            <artnr><xsl:value-of select="$itm/sku" /></artnr>
          </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:copy>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </products>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

For a working example, with source XML, see: http://xsltransform.net/pNEhB36

If you are forced to use **XSLT 1.0**, you have to use a recursive template,
calling itself again and again, up to the defined depth (one of its
parameters).

## Edit

I wrote the above example assuming that both `qty` and `sku` are
**child elements**. But now I realized that you actually wrote
that at least `qty` is an **attribute**.

So `item` element can be e.g.:

```
<item qty="2">
  <sku>23456</sku>
</item>
```

Then instead of "plain" `qty` you should write `@qty`.

Comment: Thank you very much for this detailed answer! I'm afraid the information I gave wasn't quite correct since, as you mentioned, both "qty" and "sku" are child elements, not attributes in common sense. 
I'm forced to use XSLT 1.0 though, but I am very glad for your detailed explanations!